# Change background and text color of JMenuBar and JMenu objects inside it

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jmenu, jmenubar

How can I set custom background color for `JMenuBar` and `JMenu` objects inside it? I tried `.setBackgroundColor` and it does not work!

Comment: Problem may be LAF related. Using the default LAF you only need to set the background of the menubar and the menu will inherit this color since it is non-opaque. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. If you don't know what a SSCCE is you can always search the web.

Comment: right, agreed for Nimbus L&A

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a new class that extends `JMenuBar`:

```
public class BackgroundMenuBar extends JMenuBar {
    Color bgColor=Color.WHITE;

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        bgColor=color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(bgColor);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);

    }
}
```

Now you use this class instead of `JMenuBar` and set the background color with `setColor()`.

Comment: don't forget to set on JMenu opaque to false to force inherit the colour, as this was the only thing that worked on me on Mac without using ugly `UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()` , interesting that both Linux and Windows were fine, probably because they don't use AquaMenuUI

Comment: The background works but there is a line, with the original JMenuBar color, on the bottom. The JMenu keep the original color too.

Comment: @Esses77 More than a year late but for whomever stumbles upon this, to customize the original MenuBar "line", do `menuBar.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));`, and for the Menus, do `menu.setOpaque(false)` for the menus to inherit the background color of the MenuBar.

Answer (score 12):

You would probably need to change opacity of menu items, ie:

```
JMenuItem item= new JMenuItem("Test");
item.setOpaque(true);
item.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
```

You can also achieve that globally using `UIManager`, for example:

```
UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.CYAN);
UIManager.put("MenuItem.opaque", true);
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way (I can think of) is to change the default values used by the `UIManager`.  This will effect all the menu bars and menu items in the application though...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestMenuBar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMenuBar();
    }

    public TestMenuBar() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                UIManager.put("MenuBar.background", Color.RED);
                UIManager.put("Menu.background", Color.GREEN);
                UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.MAGENTA);

                JMenu mnu = new JMenu("Testing");
                mnu.add("Menu Item 1");
                mnu.add("Menu Item 2");

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                mb.add(mnu);
                mb.add(new JMenu("Other"));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: for some reason, this does not work (at least on Mac) anymore for the JMenu, which keeps the default white color until you use `getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()` as advised above, which breaks all GUI platform-design.. e.g. ugly filechoosers everywhere

Comment: @Jiří Given the fact that this was 7 years ago, I'm not surprised

Comment: I was not surprised, but still, its something that I needed to solve even today (and I think I am not alone), so it is worth keeping things up to date... in order to paint the menu items, set `.setOpaque(false)` and paint the JMenuBar behind (override the `paintComponent()` )

Comment: how do you change the 2 white lines on the popup panel?

Comment: @francogp I suspect that it's the popup menu's background, that would be far more difficult, as it's a "common" UI element

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do is by `.setBackground(Color.RED)` and `setOpaque(true)`

```java
menubar.setBackground(Color.RED);
    menu.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    menubar.setOpaque(true);
    menu.setOpaque(true);
```

This will give the color of your choices to both the menubar and menu.

Answer (score 1):

Mine only worked when I changed:

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

to:

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Otherwise, the colors remained the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void run() {

     UIManager.put("MenuBar.background", new java.awt.Color(255, 245, 157));
     UIManager.put("MenuBar.opaque", true);                
     UIManager.put("Menu.background", new java.awt.Color(255, 245, 157));
     UIManager.put("Menu.opaque", true);
     UIManager.put("MenuItem.background",new java.awt.Color(255, 245, 157));
     UIManager.put("MenuItem.opaque", true);
     new MenuPrincipal().setVisible(true);

}
```

The menubar does not change color, but the rest do (menu and menuitem)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

**Here's the code:**

```
menu.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
```

Similarly you can add your own color like `GREEN, BLUE, DARK_GRAY, LIGHT_GRAY, BLACK, RED, etc..`

This is the only simple way to change any color of any component in java.

**Note:** This is applicable for all components in Java Swing only. it is useless in JavaFX, JFace, SWT but not AWT and Swing

Thank you,

Dereck Smith