# How to change the Background color of JMenuBar and JToolBar?

Tags: java, swing, background-color, jmenubar, jtoolbar

I want to change the background color of JMenuBar and JToolBar. For that I had tried but not working. I had followed the solutions given by some websites. But, those are also not working correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class JFrameDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public JFrameDemo() {

   Color b=new Color(0,150,255);
   initComponents();
   menuBar.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
   toolbar.setBackground(b);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    toolbar = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    close = new javax.swing.JButton();
    open = new javax.swing.JButton();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    toolbar.setRollover(true);

    close.setText("close");
    close.setFocusable(false);
    close.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    close.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    toolbar.add(close);

    open.setText("open");
    open.setFocusable(false);
    open.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    open.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    toolbar.add(open);

    menuBar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));

    jMenu3.setText("File");
    menuBar.add(jMenu3);

    jMenu4.setText("Edit");
    menuBar.add(jMenu4);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(toolbar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(toolbar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 306, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Icons\book-edit-icon.png");
            JFrameDemo fdemo=new JFrameDemo();

            fdemo.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton close;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JButton open;
private javax.swing.JToolBar toolbar;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working correctly'?

Comment: Set a nice [tag:look-and-feel].

Comment: Tip:  Add @robzillaDev (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to setOpaque(true) on your JMenuBar ?

You can also do this :

```
menuBar.setUI ( new BasicMenuBarUI (){
    public void paint ( Graphics g, JComponent c ){
       g.setColor ( YOUR_COLOR_HERE );
       g.fillRect ( 0, 0, c.getWidth (), c.getHeight () );
    }
} );
```

Or in general :

```
UIManager.put ( "MenuBarUI", YOUR_SPECIFIC_UI_HERE );
```

Comment: Okay,thank you.It's working fine.But,samething(color) I want to apply for the JToolbar also.How can I implement.Please help me....

Comment: I had applied the following code for JToolBar.  toolbar.setUI(new BasicToolBarUI(){
       @Override
       public void paint ( Graphics g, JComponent c ){
       g.setColor (Color.BLUE);
       g.fillRect ( 0, 0, c.getWidth (), c.getHeight () );
       }  
       });  I had applied color for both JMenubar and JToolbar.But,The result hide the Jtoolbar and color was applied for JMenubar.I want applied for both.Please help me...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean it dosen't set the color.
I don't know if is a glich in swing, but I have always been told to do it this way:

```
public class BackgroundMenuBar extends JMenuBar
{
    Color bgColor=Color.WHITE;

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        bgColor=color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(bgColor);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);

    }
}
```

Then you use the new Class instend of a JMenuBar, and set color with setColor.

Example take from: [SO: Change background and text color of JMenubar and...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it)

Comment: I was create the JMenuBar and JToolBar by using NetBeans IDE Because of My project is developing through IDE not manually.So,I don't know how to use above class.Please help me.

Comment: Make a the class in your UI packages (I asume you have such) then where you have menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar(); instead menuBar = new BackgroundMenuBar(); then menuBar.setColor(Color.YOUR_COLOR_CHOICH); and so on

Comment: Okay,I got it.But,I had developed this program by using NetBeans IDE.So,the source code generated by IDE is not editable.MenuBar is also IDE generated code.How can I modify it.Thank you for reply...help me

Comment: @user3556256 I hope that is not true - I my self don't use NetBeans, but if you can't edit the UI, I hope some thing is wrong