# JMenuBar and JMenu transparent

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I'm having some trouble with `JMenuBar` and `JMenu` in Ntebeans. I Just want to know can I set a custom background color for the `JMenuBar` and the `JMenu` objects inside it? I tried `setBackgroundColor()` method and it does not work! I want set white color or transparent and I tried this too :

```
menubar.setBackground(Color.RED);
menu.setBackground(Color.yellow);
menubar.setOpaque(true);
menu.setOpaque(true);
```

and still like this
[image: JMenuBar without style]

and i want some like this

[image: example]

I'm using Netbeans and when i set the preview, the JMenuBar set the background white
[JMenu Background White](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L92Ca.png)

But when i run the programm, still the same
[same color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z87TI.png)

Comment: Did you try this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it

Comment: yes i did, but still not working for me

Comment: @IsidroMartínez `still not working for me`. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. A picture doesn't help. Also what platform and LAF are you using. It code be a LAF issue.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using :

`.setBackground(Color.RED)` **and** `setOpaque(true)`

Comment: but not for me , i dont know what to do. I updated the question adding more image.

Comment: Could you post your code where you're changing color/opaque ?
May be you changed one of this on the wrong component ? Like JMenuItem insted of JMenu ?

Comment: I changed on the ritgh component:
 `jMGeneral.setBackground(Color.red);`
 `jMGeneral.setOpaque(true);`

Comment: Hum, may be it's too big, but I'm using Eclipse with the plugin "Window builder" to nearly all my graphical components, and it's working fine. May be considere using it.

Otherwise, I don't see what could be wrong except doing the setBackground/opaque on the wrong component.

Comment: i'm using NetBeans and i tried everthing, and i´m sure that im using the rigth component, even on the properties of the JMenu, i set the opaque = true and the BackGround= #ffffff... i searched so many examples and i could not foun nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set opaque as true for JMenuBar and JMenuItem because they have true as opaque value by default. However, you have set explicitly opaque as true for JMenu because its default value is false.
Thi simple code show you the default values of JMenuBar and JMenu and JMenuItem:

```java
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("My menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("My item");
    menu.add(item1);

    System.out.println(" " + menuBar.isOpaque() + ", " + menu.isOpaque() + ", " + item1.isOpaque());
```

and you will see in the console: true, false, true. So to change the background of JMenu you have set its opaque value as true.

For your desired gui here a simple code:

```java
public class TutoMenuBar extends JFrame {

    public TutoMenuBar(String nameWindow) {
        super(nameWindow);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu testingJMenu = new JMenu("Testing");
        testingJMenu.setOpaque(true);
        testingJMenu.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        menuBar.add(testingJMenu);

        JMenu otherJMenu = new JMenu("Other");
        otherJMenu.setOpaque(true);
        otherJMenu.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        menuBar.add(otherJMenu);

        JMenuItem menu_item_1JMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Menu Item 1");
        menu_item_1JMenuItem.setBackground(new Color(251, 41, 255));
        testingJMenu.add(menu_item_1JMenuItem);

        JMenuItem menu_item_2JMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Menu Item 2");
        menu_item_2JMenuItem.setBackground(new Color(251, 41, 255));
        testingJMenu.add(menu_item_2JMenuItem);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            TutoMenuBar test = new TutoMenuBar("Test");
            test.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```