# JMenuBar Background Color Not Showing

Tags: java, swing

I'm taking an introductory Java course and we're learning Swing (I know, I know, JavaFX is the latest...). Anyway, I've got GridBagLayout working, but for some reason my JMenuBar won't show a background color. I've done some digging and haven't found anything. Here's my code:

```
package com.company;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicGraphics {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Pleasant's GUI");
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenuBar myMenu = new JMenuBar();
    myMenu.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    myMenu.setOpaque(true);
    myMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,25));
    myframe.setJMenuBar(myMenu);
    Container contents = myframe.getContentPane();
    contents.setBackground(Color.blue);
    contents.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipadx = 5;
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.33;
    contents.add(lblName, c);
    JTextField tfName = new JTextField("Enter Name", 20);// columns and text
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 1;
    contents.add(tfName, c);
    JLabel lblPwd = new JLabel("Password");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.33;
    contents.add(lblPwd, c);
    JPasswordField pwdPassWord = new JPasswordField(10);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    contents.add(pwdPassWord, c);
    JLabel lblGender = new JLabel("Gender");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weightx = 0.33;
    contents.add(lblGender, c);
    ButtonGroup bgGender = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton rbMale = new JRadioButton("Male");
    JRadioButton rbFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
    bgGender.add(rbMale);
    bgGender.add(rbFemale);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    contents.add(rbMale, c);
    c.gridy = 3;
    contents.add(rbFemale, c);
    //add to panel and show flow layout by changing order
    //& resize window.  Change BorderLayout to CENTER
    myframe.pack();
    myframe.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which is work in window 7 with jdk 1.8 which color the `JMenuBar` as well as `JMenu` also.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class BasicGraphics
    {
        JFrame frame;
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu fileMenu;
        JMenu editMenu;
        public BasicGraphics()
        {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.setOpaque(true);
            menuBar.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
            fileMenu.setBackground(Color.RED);

            editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
            editMenu.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            menuBar.add(fileMenu);
            menuBar.add(editMenu);

            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new BasicGraphics();
    }
 }
```

`setOpaque(true);` is definitely work , it color the `JMenuBar`, I am not understand that why is not work in your computer.Your code is also color the `JMenuBar` in orange.Here is the Image

[image]