# Why Java JMenubar becomes black?

Tags: java, swing

I test a simple file to render menu bar, but, it fails by showing a black bar on the top. I don't know why this happen, code is following. Thanks for any helps.

result img here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OQGy.png]

```
public class test01 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 800);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    // setup the file menu for the manager
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JMenu file1 = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu file2 = new JMenu("Size");
    menuBar.add(file1);
    menuBar.add(file2);


    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: See if this [anwer your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it) and please, let me know ;)

Comment: It works for me on Windows 10 with the default look and feel. The background remains gray if I use the system look and feel.