# Override UIManager in java

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

I have a Java swing notepad project, where I used `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())` to change my look and feel on my **windows-10 professional**. I have a Menubar and a few menus, I want to set their background colour to cyan.

I tried using

```
JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
mb.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
```

Also, I tried with and without

`mb.setOpaque(true);`

and

`mb.setOpaque(false);`

but it stays white, I tried the same with other colors, but none worked.

But this works for other components such as `JTextArea`, but not for the menubar and menus only, but I can change the foreground color of the Menus using the `mb.setForeground()` method, I can change the Menubar background only if I remove the `UIManager(...)` line, but I need the windows look and feel for some functions in the program.

Current output:
[image: Current output]

Required output:
[image: Required output]

The buggy code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class withUIM{
    private static final JTextArea pad = new JTextArea();
    private static JLabel statusBar = new JLabel("||       Ln 1, Col 1  ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    private static JFrame f = new JFrame("Overriding UIManager");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FF00"));
        statusBar.setOpaque(true);
        statusBar.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        statusBar.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(pad), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JLabel dummy = new JLabel("  ");
        dummy.setOpaque(true);
        dummy.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JLabel dummy1 = new JLabel("  ");
        dummy1.setOpaque(true);
        dummy1.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        f.add(dummy, BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.add(dummy1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.setOpaque(true);
        mb.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("file");
        fileMenu.setOpaque(false);
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("edit");
        editMenu.setOpaque(false);
        JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("format");
        formatMenu.setOpaque(false);
        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("view");
        viewMenu.setOpaque(false);
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("help");
        helpMenu.setOpaque(false);
        mb.add(fileMenu);
        mb.add(editMenu);
        mb.add(formatMenu);
        mb.add(viewMenu);
        mb.add(helpMenu);
        f.add(mb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it/15650134#15650134)?

Comment: *(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()* - well what is the OS you are using? Maybe the LAF for the OS doesn't allow you do override the background. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem so people using the same OS can try the code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I tried the solutions you linked before posting this question, but they did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for method [setBackground](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) (in class `javax.swing.JComponent`):

> It is up to the look and feel to honor this property, some may choose to ignore it.

So it looks like `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` does ignore the *background* property.

One option would be to create a custom [look-and-feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html).

Another option would be to use `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel`.

I assume that calling `setOpaque(false)` for every `JMenu` is just you trying to solve your problem. In the code below, I got rid of those calls.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class withUIM {
    private static final JTextArea pad = new JTextArea();
    private static JLabel statusBar = new JLabel("||       Ln 1, Col 1  ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    private static JFrame f = new JFrame("Overriding UIManager");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FF00"));
        statusBar.setOpaque(true);
        statusBar.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        statusBar.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(pad), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JLabel dummy = new JLabel("  ");
        dummy.setOpaque(true);
        dummy.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JLabel dummy1 = new JLabel("  ");
        dummy1.setOpaque(true);
        dummy1.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        f.add(dummy, BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.add(dummy1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("file");
        fileMenu.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("edit");
        editMenu.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("format");
        formatMenu.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("view");
        viewMenu.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("help");
        helpMenu.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FFFF"));
        mb.add(fileMenu);
        mb.add(editMenu);
        mb.add(formatMenu);
        mb.add(viewMenu);
        mb.add(helpMenu);
        f.add(mb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Screen capture:

[image: screen capture]